# How to sort my xml in Listview by pubdate in android

Tags: android, parsing, listview

I have an Rss feed that i'm parsing.  I need it to sort and organize from top to bottom by pubdate.  Here is the code that i'm using.

XML Parser

```
public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
 }
```

Parsing Activity

```
 public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.cpcofc.org/devoapp.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "item";
static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "description";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_DESC, KEY_NAME, KEY_COST}, new int[] {
                    R.id.desciption, R.id.name, R.id.cost});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
 }
```

Here is what it looks like right now

[image]

I need to show the reverse of this with day 1 at the top.  Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to reverse the order of the List in order to achieve what you want,
we can use Collections class provided by java collection framework  ... here is the simple code

```
Collections.reverse(menuItems);
```

it will reverse your collection.... I hope this  will help you

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't need to override sort the ArrayAdapter class implements that for you. All you need to do is create your own Comparator that will sort the generic type objects the way you want them to appear. Also,  Your code should work correctly if you use this approach.

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list,R.id.title, data);

adapter.sort(new Comparator<RowData>() {
    public int compare(RowData arg0, RowData arg1) {
        return arg0.mProductName.compareTo(arg1.mProductName);
    }
});

setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

For more reference..

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_filtersort

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 0):

both previous answers will cost you some performance because they loop through the ArrayList AT LEAST once.

you can simply use a reverse iterator for your loop like this:

```
 int len = nl.getLength();
 for (int i = len; i > 0; --i)
```

i also extracted the length of the array into a local variable cause it's way faster than calling the getLength method every time.